# Switch WIFI driver?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, iwlwifi

I think my old WIFI card died a while back. I kept trying different versions of Linux to see if that would bring back my WIFI. Then, I thought my ethernet card was my WIFI card. Now, I got an Intel Centrino Advanced N 6200, model # 622ANHMW. I put it in my Lenova Thinkpad X201 laptop, model # 3680-EU2 and, on bootup, get the message to remove the unauthorized WIFI card.

I see the driver I need in /lib/firmware, iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode, but how do I get it all to work together and "play nice"? Both WIFI cards are removed from my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen wifi cards die.  It is quite possible that is the case here.  I have also encountered two laptops, one an HP, which had (for apparently no legitimate reason) configured the bios to only accept wifi cards specifically configured for that laptop.  In that situation I went onto amazon and searched until I found one which specifically stated it would work with that one laptop, it was cheap and it solved the problem.

As for drivers, I suggest you install the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) which can easily be installed by opening [This Link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/), and then pressing the orange install button.  Synaptic can be searched for specific drivers, and driver packages, some of which will support wifi devices not ordinarily supported by Ubuntu.

In your case however I'm going to go out on a limb and GUESS you were using Ubuntu 14.04 which has been "persnickity" about wifi support.

Comment: I would like to offer a minor suggestion which may or may not be adequate to your situation.  It is possible your laptop, which I have not looked up, has a sufficient number of usb connectors that you could stand to use an extremely low profile external wifi adapter (literally 1/8" protrusion) and just leave it there.  I've encountered only three problems with these.  1) low range  2) occasional overheating  3) certain particular brands don't appear to work at all well.  Look for those primarily black with a red trim band.  I may return later with a link to the one I carry for emergencies.

Comment: but 14.04 supports that card. I just don't know how to select that driver as the one to use. I do not think any WIFI driver is being used because I think I did  not have a working WIFI card when I installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Not having a working card at installation will not prevent ubuntu from installing one.  You can also try clicking on "additional drivers" under "system settings".  It will search for any "new hardware" not already supported.  Of course for this to work you need to have a working internet connection, so I must hope you have a wired ethernet connection.

Comment: I have found the adapter I carry and there's good and bad news.  First, which usb adapter to avoid:  avoid this one!  http://amzn.com/B0058XSZGU    Due to the brand, I would assume this one to be a safe bet:  http://amzn.com/B004VDR37K   I particularly recommend this one, which can still be found online but sadly no longer at amazon:  http://amzn.com/B00E8GPDZO

Comment: I have 3 USB slots. One for a scrolling mouse, one for a not so occasional flash drive and one for USB mini light (because I often find myself working with inadequate light). USB WIFI does look better and better though. And my laptop already overheats if asked to go in more than one direction at the same time.

Comment: It sounds to me that all three of your usb devices are the sort to get unplugged any time your laptop is picked up and moved, so here's a thought.  You could buy the "cute usb mini 2-port hub"  http://amzn.com/B00A81ISJ6  You should probably plug the micro wifi into one of its two slots and the mouse into the other and keep it on the end of the mouse cable so it always gets connected.

Comment: WOAH!  I just realized your laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad.  I was explaining to a friend only yesterday that these are purported to be the most thoroughly supported linux laptops on the planet for the reason that these laptops are the most popular among linux developers.  Perhaps you can find a BIOS upgrade for it at the Lenovo website?

Comment: I bought a Linux compatible mini pcix half size for less than $10. I can now use the 5Ghz WIFI like the big dogs. I have yet to run a antenna cable from the card to somewhere.. like the backside of my screen.

Comment: I also upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS.